# Android Cannot resolve symbol PlusDomains

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-plus

I'm following the Google+ Domains API OAuth tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/), but I'm having trouble importing PlusDomains. I have

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
```

in build.gradle, but Android Studio tells me there's nothing to import and is asking me to create the class. I've got the most recent Android SDK. My build.gradle is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "something.edu.androidoauth"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
}
```

I have no idea what else to try. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the correct dependency is

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-plusDomains:v1-rev457-1.23.0'
```

I'm not really sure then what com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1 is for.